# Css3: right trapezoid with border

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a `transparent` right trapezoid with `color` border using `CSS 3` This is what I've gotten so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/bodyfarmer/bdhtn7kr/1/

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place a right border on the containing object to get the correct look.  Like this:

```
border-right: 20px solid red;
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdhtn7kr/6/)

I also changed skew to skewX.  Per this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

> Note: The skew() function was present in early drafts. It has been
>   removed but is still present in some implementations. Do not use it.
>
> To achieve the same effect, use skewX() if you were using skew() with
>   one parameter or matrix(1, tan(ay), tan(ax), 1, 0, 0) for the general
>   way. Note that tan() isn't a CSS function and you have to precalculate
>   it yourself.

Comment: You can also use: `box-sizing: border-box;`, so that you don't have to recomputed heights of the elements when you change the border width.

Comment: I'm trying implement that shape with bootstrap grid. The height hasn't been responsive. Maybe you have insight into this? http://jsfiddle.net/bodyfarmer/55sx5esp/

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are missing part of the border rule.

`border: 20px solid red;`

Comment: It's just border shorthand? That's not it I don't think

Comment: Maybe Im misunderstanding the question?  I'd suggest maybe posting a screenshot of what you what it to look like.

Comment: Nevermind...  It looks like @kaz answered it correctly.  I totally misunderstood what you were asking.